# Motochopper root failure message

Tags: rooting, macos

I want to use Motochopper to root my Samsung Galaxy Fame, but I found this failure message at the end. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
[*]
[*] Motochopper: Android root exploit (Linux/OS X version)
[*] v1.1
[*] by Dan Rosenberg (@djrbliss)
[*]
[*] Tested on the Motorola Razr HD, Razr M, Razr Maxx HD, and Atrix HD.
[*] Supports lots of other devices as well. ;-)
[*]
[*] Before continuing, ensure that USB debugging is enabled and that
[*] your phone is connected via USB.
[*]
[*] WARNING: This will likely void the warranty on your device. I am
[*] not responsible for any damage to your phone as a result using this
[*] tool.
[*]
[*] Press enter to root your phone...

[*]
[*] Waiting for device...
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
[*] Device found.
[*] Pushing exploit...
5268 KB/s (1283460 bytes in 0.237s)
[*] Pushing root tools...
5932 KB/s (366952 bytes in 0.060s)
5410 KB/s (1867568 bytes in 0.337s)
4336 KB/s (1578585 bytes in 0.355s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Superuser.apk
Success
[*] Rooting phone...
[+] This may take a few minutes.
[-] Failure.
[*] Cleaning up...
[*] Exploit complete. Press enter to reboot and exit.
```

Details:

Computer: OSX

Device: Samsung Galaxy Fame GT-S681OP

Android Version: 4.1.2

The problem: I get the failure message just before `cleaning up` and this is the run.sh file:

```
echo "[*]"
echo "[*] Motochopper: Android root exploit (Linux/OS X version)"
echo "[*] v1.1"
echo "[*] by Dan Rosenberg (@djrbliss)"
echo "[*]"
echo "[*] Tested on the Motorola Razr HD, Razr M, Razr Maxx HD, and Atrix HD."
echo "[*] Supports lots of other devices as well. ;-)"
echo "[*]"
echo "[*] Before continuing, ensure that USB debugging is enabled and that"
echo "[*] your phone is connected via USB."
echo "[*]"
echo "[*] WARNING: This will likely void the warranty on your device. I am"
echo "[*] not responsible for any damage to your phone as a result using this"
echo "[*] tool."
echo "[*]"
echo "[*] Press enter to root your phone..."

read -n 1

echo "[*]"

platform=`uname`
if [ $(uname -p) = 'powerpc' ]; then
        echo "[-] PowerPC is not supported."
        exit 1
fi

if [ "$platform" = 'Darwin' ]; then
        adb="./adb.osx"
        version="OS X"
else
        adb="./adb.linux"
        version="Linux"
fi
chmod +x $adb

$adb kill-server

echo "[*] Waiting for device..."
$adb wait-for-device

echo "[*] Device found."

echo "[*] Pushing exploit..."
$adb push pwn /data/local/tmp/
$adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/pwn

echo "[*] Pushing root tools..."
$adb push su /data/local/tmp/
$adb push busybox /data/local/tmp/
$adb install Superuser.apk

echo "[*] Rooting phone..."
$adb shell /data/local/tmp/pwn

echo "[*] Cleaning up..."
$adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/pwn
$adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/su
$adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/busybox

echo "[*] Exploit complete. Press enter to reboot and exit."
read -n 1
$adb reboot
$adb kill-server

Here is the problem:

echo "[*] Rooting phone..."
$adb shell /data/local/tmp/pwn

echo "[*] Cleaning up..."
$adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/pwn
$adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/su
$adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/busy
```

so `$adb shell /data/local/tmp/pwn` is causing problems, but how to fix? Anyone knows?